# Is the size of $\varepsilon$-nets of the Euclidean ball exponential for large $\varepsilon$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be the unit ball of $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_2)$. A finite set $N=N(\varepsilon)$ is a $\varepsilon$-net of $X$ if every point in $X$ is at most a distance $\varepsilon$ from a point from $N$.

It is well-known that $N(\varepsilon)=(O(1)/\varepsilon)^n$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. My question is whether there exists a function $\varepsilon(n)$ such that for all $\varepsilon>\varepsilon(n)$ there exists a $\varepsilon$-net of size $1/\varepsilon^2$ (or some other dimension-free quantity). Of course, this question only becomes interesting when $\varepsilon(n)<1$.

Comment: Since the balls of radius $\epsilon$ centered at points of any $\epsilon$-net $N$ cover $X$, by volume comparison we have $\operatorname{card}(N )\ge\epsilon^{-n}$. If $\operatorname{card}N\le1/\epsilon^2$ it is needed $\epsilon^{n-2}\ge1$, so there should be no $\epsilon(n)<1$ as you want if $n>2$.

Comment: Thanks! That is neat. I am new to this, so I don't know how to declare this as an answer. I apologize.